# Macbook Pro 2010 15" keeps crashing randomly with no warning

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic, gpu

I have started experiencing random crashes from my 2010 Macbook Pro 15"

It has not symptoms before it crashes, and it doesn't happen on a timely basis but it does happen once every few days, sometimes it will happen multiple times within the hour.

Here is the crash report from the latest incident:

```
Anonymous UUID:       7E16DAAF-17F6-F0C8-8EE6-C2A3BB5F5E53

Sat Oct 17 10:28:38 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f98c48c1b): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff8131c03000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.10.25/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8120962f50 : 0xffffff8015f2ad21 
0xffffff8120962fd0 : 0xffffff7f98c48c1b 
0xffffff81209630b0 : 0xffffff7f96adeb9f 
0xffffff8120963170 : 0xffffff7f96ba818e 
0xffffff81209631b0 : 0xffffff7f96ba81fe 
0xffffff8120963220 : 0xffffff7f96e27056 
0xffffff8120963350 : 0xffffff7f96bcb82d 
0xffffff8120963370 : 0xffffff7f96ae55f1 
0xffffff8120963420 : 0xffffff7f96ae30fc 
0xffffff8120963620 : 0xffffff7f96ae4a4b 
0xffffff81209636f0 : 0xffffff7f981acefa 
0xffffff8120963860 : 0xffffff7f9818f98d 
0xffffff81209638a0 : 0xffffff7f9815b0f5 
0xffffff8120963a20 : 0xffffff7f9818c3c1 
0xffffff8120963ae0 : 0xffffff7f98159c15 
0xffffff8120963b30 : 0xffffff80164ffed6 
0xffffff8120963b60 : 0xffffff80165015eb 
0xffffff8120963bc0 : 0xffffff80164fed83 
0xffffff8120963d00 : 0xffffff8015fe1307 
0xffffff8120963e10 : 0xffffff8015f2ef8c 
0xffffff8120963e40 : 0xffffff8015f139f3 
0xffffff8120963e90 : 0xffffff8015f2429d 
0xffffff8120963f10 : 0xffffff801600231a 
0xffffff8120963fb0 : 0xffffff80160344c6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.10.25)[752C63EA-73E8-39BC-8225-3A97D0C403BF]@0xffffff7f98c3a000->0xffffff7f98c4dfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.25)[3DC2F93F-5197-3B16-8975-0142E7A0474B]@0xffffff7f98c32000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f969c5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f96740000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f96a37000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[65E3187E-949B-36E9-BA33-1B13ABB0581A]@0xffffff7f98c35000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f96a8e000->0xffffff7f96cf7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f96740000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f96a7e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f96a37000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f96d02000->0xffffff7f96fabfff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f96a8e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f96740000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[59758864-B0B8-3ED7-B4B9-DBBFAC568F35]@0xffffff7f98147000->0xffffff7f98214fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BDA92C3B-AD86-33E5-A7F1-1603465350A7]@0xffffff7f96740000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[7372D580-6DDE-3457-B043-49B8447FC9D2]@0xffffff7f96a7e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[8922721D-5517-3883-BD3A-57422D0244A0]@0xffffff7f96a37000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f96a8e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Preview
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14F27

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 58F06365-45C7-3CA7-B80D-173AFD1A03C4
Kernel slide:     0x0000000015c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015d00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16657306028724
last loaded kext at 9860477580201: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC 4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f98db6000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 9934457346677: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f98db6000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner   10.9.0
org.pqrs.driver.NoEjectDelay    6.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.6f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.25
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.25
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.6f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 398
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x02BA, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x02BA, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series, 256.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02, 500.11 GB
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Is there some loose hardware or something?

EDIT: It has happened again and here is the corresponding crash report: http://pastebin.com/hmDHuUu6

Comment: This particular crash log shows this: `BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Preview`. Do other crashes occur just with Preview or with other apps, too?

Comment: i dont know which app they occur with, as i usually have about 2-3 preview  windows open and 10-15 chrome tabs split across 5 desktops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you have the same logic board issue that I have. There was a batch of faulty logic boards in the mid 2010 MacBook Pro. Apple replaced the Logic boards in faulty MBPs free of charge at the time, but unfortunately their offer only lasted for MBPs reported to them within 3 years of purchase. Like yourself, my MBP only started showing the problem after the 3 years were up.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4152749?tstart=0

The issue is due to the automatic switching between the intel GPU and the Nvidia GPU.

The only way I've found to live with the issue is to install [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) and lock my graphics card to the intel GPU. Others have a little more success and are able to lock their GPU to the Nvidia chip and suffer the battery life drop. Mileage seems to vary with the solution.

You could try contacting Apple and beg them to fix the logic board for you as it is a known issue, but I've no idea how you'll get on as their replacement program ended a while back.

Answer (score 0):

The gfx card status will only work with this version 1.8.1
https://software.com/mac/apps/gfxcardstatus/1.8.1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions